# Rasberry Pi 3 a+ monitor not working blank screen

Tags: screen

I just bought a 3A+ Pi. I'm not seeing anything on a computer or tv screen when HDMI is plugged in. I did the following trouble shoots:

- Used different computer screens and tv.
- Plugged in different wires (HDMI wires).
- Tried another Rasberry Pi I bought.
- Red Solid light is turned on.
- PI-Mouse, keyboard, and power adapter being used.
- Mouse is on has red ligt.
- Plugged in all cables and power cable last.
- Screens turned on and plugged in prior to plugging in power.

The only issue again is I'm not able to see anything on a screen. If anyone could help that would be great.

Comment: To rule out the obvious, have you burned an sd card and installed it before booting?

Comment: Hello, I'm using the SD car provided with the computer kit (Pi computer, keyboard, mouse, power supply, SD card and Case.) From my understanding it was loaded with software already.

Comment: @user128149, it would still be a good idea to try another SD card. The steps to download and install the OS are here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/